# Предупреждение AndroidStudio при указании xml-drawable значением фона в разметке android:drawable="@drawable/button"

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-studio

При создании android:drawable="@drawable/button появляется восклицательный знак в  красном кругу.
[image: что это и как убрать?]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на этот знак , переходит на buttton.xml
Что делаю не так?

Comment: что это и как исправить ?

Comment: Если навести, что пишет?

Comment: не чего. только на нажатие реагирует

Comment: Покажи тогда button.xml

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 4):

Ошибок нет. Это означает, что студия не смогла показать превью изображения. Если выбрать изображение то там будет показано превью.
Ответ взят с [англоязычной версии сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029295/android-studio-shows-red-exclamation-at-drawable-attribute)

Comment: Да на самом деле превью показывает не корректно , так как много LinearLayout во  фрагменте. Спасибо , я всю голову сломал .Значит это не ошибка и на корректность работы не повлияет?

Comment: Не ошибка, у меня проект из 30 лэйаутов просто кишит подобными варнингами, никто не жаловался еще, что не работает бэграунд.  
И если есть реально ошибка, то ты об этом узнаешь сразу. Например не скомпилируется.